# Initial space validation for Edittext in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

How to set validation for EditText when user enters first character as a space i.e. " ".
However I want to use space in all other cases. Only first character should not be a space.
If user enters space then I'll disable the SEND button, other wise the SEND button will be enabled.

Could you please suggest. I tried with TextWatcher's onTextChanged method. But it's not working as expected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with the following code:

```
mUiEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            if (charSequence.toString().startsWith(" ")) {
                //disableButton(...)
            } else {
                //enableButton(...)
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work with a TextWatcher, did you try something like that:

```
input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String text = s.toString();
        if(text.charAt(0) == ' ')
            button.setClickable(false);
        else
            button.setClickable(true);
    }
});
```